# How to set value of one input field based on another input field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addeventlistener

I am trying to set the value of slug field by manipulating the input of another field title using JavaScript. When I type in the slug and then again i start typing in the title field the value of slug field doesn't get updated. here is my form

```js
document.getElementById('title').addEventListener("input", function(){
    let title = document.getElementById('title').value;       
    console.log(title);
    title = title.toLowerCase();
    title = title.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
    document.getElementById('slug').setAttribute("value", title);
    console.log(document.getElementById('slug').value);
});
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="http://laravel.dv/admin/blog/post/store" id="create-post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="2HeXBBKd1HSmpuGvjYqF1KygbGsCQaZtkuUthi1s">            <div class="page-title">
      <h1>Create A Blog</h1>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-control">
          <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="" placeholder="Title" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" value="" placeholder="Slug" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-control">
          <input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Image upload">
      </div>
      <div style="margin: 0 0 20px;">
          <textarea name="body" id="summernote"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-12">
          <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn-primary" value="Save Post" />
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Event Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

Always pass the Event Object⁰ to an event listener/handler/callback:

> ```
> document.forms[0].addEventListener("input", syncData); 
>            ³                                     ²
> function syncData(eventObj) {...
>            ¹         ⁰
> ```

Note that the callback `function syncData()`¹ is a named function that's not wrapped in the event listener. Also note that when called by an event listener/handler the parenthesis `()`² are removed. The reason why is because when rendered, `()` would run immediately rather than run when a registered event is fired. One last thing for this part is the DOM Object registered to the input event: `document.forms[0]`. That is a reference to the `<form>` tag via [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms) interface

---

#### [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) & [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

The event properties: `Event.target`¹ and `Event.currentTarget`⁰ come from the Event Object. `e.target` is a reference to the tag that was clicked, inputted, etc. (ex. `#slug`) and `e.currentTarget` is a reference to the ancestor tag that's registered to the event (ex. `form`). The `form.elements` is an array-like object that contains all form fields of a given `form`, the [`.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)² property makes it possible to reference any of form controls by `id` or `name` -- this: `form.elements.fields.title.value` is the same as: `document.getElementById('title').value;`

> ```
>   const form = e.currentTarget;⁰
>   const active = e.target;¹
>   const fields = form.elements;²
> ```

---

### Demo

I wasn't 100% sure about how you wanted the text input behavior so I made the typing in sync both ways.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .as-console-wrapper {
      width: 350px;
      min-height: 100%;
      margin-left: 45%;
    }
    
    .as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
      content: '';
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border: 0;
      width: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST" action="http://laravel.dv/admin/blog/post/store" id="create-post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="2HeXBBKd1HSmpuGvjYqF1KygbGsCQaZtkuUthi1s">
    <div class="page-title">
      <h1>Create A Blog</h1>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-control">
          <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="" placeholder="Title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" value="" placeholder="Slug">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
          <input type="file" name="image" placeholder="Image upload">
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 0 0 20px;">
          <textarea name="body" id="summernote"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn-primary" value="Save Post" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script>
    document.forms[0].addEventListener("input", syncData);

    function syncData(e) {
      const form = e.currentTarget;
      const active = e.target;
      const fields = form.elements;
      let txt;
      if (active.type === 'text') {
        txt = active.value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
        console.log(txt);
        active.title = txt;
        fields.title.value = txt;
        fields.slug.value = txt;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi try using the value property instead:

```
document.getElementById('title').addEventListener("input", function(){
  let title = document.getElementById('title').value;        
  console.log(title);
  title = title.toLowerCase();
  title = title.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
  document.getElementById('slug').value = title;
  console.log(document.getElementById('slug').value);
});
```

Should work :)

This is because value should be accessed with the dot notation and also setAttribute is used to modify the original value of the input which in your case is not present

Comment: Please explain why this works so the OP can understand your change.

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm adding an explanation